# Sometimes the cursor is invisible,but it still operates

Tags: mouse, cursor

Sometimes this happens,when I boot into ubuntu,the logon screen has no cursor,but when i move it,it still operates,i log in,and it is still invisible. If I log out,then log back i,the cursor reappears. Is there a permanent fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue too when running:

```
  gterm (locally) -> ssh -> screen (remotely) -> bash
```

In some of the screen windows, the cursor worked fine in others it was blank.  I could use SCREEN_COMMAND+ESC+7 to get the cursor to blink but then it would stop when I typed in the window.  I ended up exiting that bash session and restarting it.  Most likely a screen issue.